# jQuery hiding all element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My function is hiding all elements. In input black color is selected. can you please explain me why it happening and if you want to check code then you can go to my website http://newseinstein.com/Rwork/index.php/Listing

```js
$(".color").click(function() {
  var color = [];
  var i = 0;

  $(".color").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
      $("*[data-color]").val($(this).val()).hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="yellow">Color yellow</div>
<div data-color="red">Color red</div>
<div data-color="red">Color red</div>


<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="Black">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="yellow">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="red">
```

Comment: Please be more specific, it is very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're using the setter of `val()`. This then returns all the elements being iterated over and then calls `hide()` on them.

To fix this you can select the elements based on their maching `data-color` attribute and then toggle them, based on the state of the `checked` property of the checkbox. Try this:

```js
$(".color").click(function() {
  var color = [];
  var i = 0;

  $('.color').each(function() {
     $('div[data-color="' + this.value + '"]').toggle(this.checked);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="yellow">Color yellow</div>
<div data-color="red">Color red</div>
<div data-color="red">Color red</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="black">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="yellow">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="red">
```

Also note that you set the `value` of one of the checkboxes to `Black`, when it should be `black` to match the case of the data attribute values.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting value using `.val()` and then using `.hide()` to hiding all. You need to `hide()` all the div's and  then display only the filtered elements

```js
var divs = $("div[data-color]"); //Get all elements
var colors = $(".color").change(function() {
  divs.hide(); //Start with hiding all
  //iterate checked checkboxes 
  colors.filter(':checked').each(function() {
    //filter element based on attribute and show
    divs.filter("[data-color='" + $(this).val() + "']").show();
  });
})
```

```css
div[data-color] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="black">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="yellow">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox color" name="color[]" value="red">
<br>

<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="black">Color black</div>
<div data-color="yellow">Color yellow</div>
<div data-color="red">Color red</div>
<div data-color="red">Color red</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're not checking the value of your data attributes correctly.

What you're doing is selecting all elements that have a `data-color` attribute - regardless of what that is set as - then setting the value of that element (interesting, on a `<div>`) and then hiding it. You need to select only the elements where the `data-color` attribute matches what you're looking for.

```
$(".color").click(function(){
    var color = [];
    var i = 0;

    $(".color").each(function(){
        var selectedColor = $(this).val();
        if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("*[data-color='" + selectedColor + "']").hide();
        }
    });
})
```